# AngularJs binding value does not show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jointjs

I am trying to update a element value through {{}}. Here is my HTML.

```
  <section id="eee" ng-controller="DiagCtrl" <input type="hidden" id="lst" name = "lst" value="{{process_list(lst)}}">>
    <h2><a href="#eee">EEE</a></h2>
    <div id="paper" ></div>
    <div id="tt" ng-model="toolTip" ><span >{{toolTip}}</span > </div>
  </section>
```

on mouseover event call the controller.

```
paper.on('cell:mouseover', 
    function(cellView, evt) { 
      var t = cellView.model.attributes.attrs.text.text;
      angular.element(document.getElementById("eee")).scope().setTooltip(t);
      cellView.model.attributes.attrs.title = t;
    }
);
```

The controller

```
app.controller("DiagCtrl", function ($scope, getApiDataService) {
   $scope.lst = [];
   $scope.toolTip = [];   
   $scope.setTooltip = function (table) {
      $scope.toolTip = table;
   }
   $scope.process_list = function (list) {
      add_cell(list);
   }
});
```

The {{toolTip }} does not get set even after mousever event. What I am missing here?

Comment: Is there a typo in your first line of html?

Comment: Yeah this is odd ```<section id="eee" ng-controller="DiagCtrl" <input type="hidden"```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I would fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-model` directive doesn't work with `<div>` tags. It works with `<input>` and `<select>` tags.

To set something on mouseover, use the `ng-mouseover` directive.

```
<span ng-mouseover="setToolTip('hello')">{{toolTip}}</span >
```

JS

```
$scope.setTooltip = function (table) {
    $scope.toolTip = table;
};
```